# Press save button of "File download dialog" of internet explorer via c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, download, sendkeys

I am working on internet explorer automation and part of it involves downloading files from a site whcih is hosted on asp 2.0 and uses forms based authentication, so to create end to end automation I used browser automation.

I was able to reach to the step where I can get to click on a URL which brings the "File Download" dialog of the browser, then I was trying to make use of SendKeys to click on the save button but to no avail it was not working.

Here is the code where I make use of FindWindow method to get the hWnd pointer of the File Download Dialog, and then using setActiveWindow I make it the active window so that the SendKeys commands works on it and then using SendKeys I tried to send Alt + S but it didn't work. I observed that, Tab, Escape and Enter works, but then Enter on Save button doesn't work.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "File Download");
    IntPtr nullptr = (IntPtr)0;
    if (hwnd != nullptr)
    {
        SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%S");
    }
}
```

Using the same code I was able to access notepad by changing the value in FindWindow to "Untitled - Notepad".

Do I need to do something different as it is a dialog and now a window? I am using IE8.

This is the alternate code I tried after the answer.

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "File Download");
            IntPtr hokBtn = IntPtr.Zero;
            hokBtn = FindWindowEx(hwnd, hokBtn, "Button", IntPtr.Zero);
            hokBtn = FindWindowEx(hwnd, hokBtn, "Button", IntPtr.Zero);
            uint id = GetDlgCtrlID(hokBtn);
            SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
            IntPtr res = SendMessage(hokBtn, (int)0x00F5, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (res.ToInt32() == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("success");
```

For clarity I am adding the screen of the dialog.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4f23586401.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4f23586401.png)

Comment: Have you written your own automation application or are you using something like Selenium?

Comment: i have written my own automation, which is pretty trivial. It essentially takes the IE Application object, navigates to a url. Logins using DOM and then clicks on a URL which brings the download dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following which seemed to work for me:

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "File Download");
IntPtr hokBtn = FindWindowEx(hwnd, null, "Button", "Cancel");
uint id = GetDlgCtrlID(hokBtn);
SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
IntPtr res = SendMessage(hokBtn, (int)0x00F5, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
if (res.ToInt32() == 1)
    MessageBox.Show("success");
```

I would suggest you check the returns from each function though.

Answer (score 2):

This works in C++
Note that the 'Save' button is named '&Save' not 'Save'

```
CString Title;
    Title=_T("File Download");
    HWND FEX =  ::FindWindowEx( NULL,NULL,NULL,Title);
    if (FEX != NULL)
    {

        //press the Save button on the dialog.
        HWND hokBtn = ::FindWindowEx(FEX, NULL, L"Button", L"&Save");
        if (hokBtn != NULL)
        {

            UINT id = ::GetDlgCtrlID(hokBtn);
            ::SetActiveWindow(hokBtn);
            ::PostMessage(hokBtn, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x20, 0);
            ::PostMessage(hokBtn, WM_KEYUP, 0x20, 0);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

well, you have to find window with title of downloading dialog. and than you have to find window with title of download button/ and then send to that window click message

```
  BM_CLICK = 0x00F5

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parent, IntPtr next, string sClassName, IntPtr sWindowTitle);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint GetDlgCtrlID(IntPtr hWnd); 

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

    //hDialog  - handle of dialog window. idBtn - Id of button
     public static bool ClickButtonOnDialog(IntPtr hDialog, UInt32 idBtn)
    {
        IntPtr res = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint id;
        IntPtr hOkBtn = IntPtr.Zero;
        int attempt = 0;
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            //searching for button
            hOkBtn = User32.FindWindowEx(hDialog, hOkBtn, "Button", IntPtr.Zero);
            id = User32.GetDlgCtrlID(hOkBtn);
            attempt++;
        } while (id != idBtn && attempt < 20);
        if (!hOkBtn.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            //click the button
            res = User32.SendMessage(hOkBtn, (int)WindowsMessages.BM_CLICK, 1,  IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        if (res.ToInt32() == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

and you can use winspector (analog of spy++). it's very useful utility. You can discovery many things about windows;)

Comment: see the updated question, res is returning 0. and in spy++ though i can see click message is being registered but it is not foring the window to load the file save dialog.

Comment: so, you can try send mouse down and up events

Answer (score 1):

**I found a way to do this with Internet Explorer 6 in Windows XP.**

(Sorry, VBA code)

```
'ButtonHwnd is the pointer to the Save button
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Long = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Long = &H4
Dim pos As RECT
' We get the button position
GetWindowRect ButtonHwnd, pos

' We simulate an entering of the cursor in the button. IE think this is a human :-).
' We need three steps: out, entering and in.
' Out
SetCursorPos (pos.Left - 10), (pos.Top - 10)
Sleep 100
' Entering
SetCursorPos pos.Left, pos.Top
Sleep 100
' In
SetCursorPos (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2

' We do clic with the left button. You can use SendInput instead
' With 400 miliseconds it works.
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2, 0, 0
Sleep 400
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, (pos.Left + pos.Right) / 2, (pos.Top + pos.Bottom) / 2, 0, 0
```

**Please, tell if it works for you.**

Answer (score 1):

I found most of this on StackOverflow:  [How to handle Message Boxes while using webbrowser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770522/how-to-handle-message-boxes-while-using-webbrowser-in-c)
and i modified it for me

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //for the dll import (to press a key)

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private async void downloadstuff()
{
await Task.Delay(40000);  //i need this delay, but you might not :)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download");  //this is the window it finds
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save");  //this is the button to pres
    uint message = 0xf5;
    SendMessage(hwnd, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
await Task.Delay(1000);
{
    IntPtr hwnd2 = FindWindow("#32770", "Save As");
    hwnd2 = FindWindowEx(hwnd2, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save");
    uint message2 = 0xf5;
    SendMessage(hwnd2, message2, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
await Task.Delay(1000);                //i press it anyway, just in case :)
{   //this is the download complete box (if its checked it doesn't show up)
    IntPtr hwnd3 = FindWindow("#32770", "Download complete");
    hwnd3 = FindWindowEx(hwnd3, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Close");
    uint message3 = 0xf5;
    SendMessage(hwnd3, message3, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
}
```

Comment: too much of code and less description is not welcomed. Please explain the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "File Download");
IntPtr hokBtn = FindWindowEx(hwnd, null, "Button", "Cancel");
uint id = GetDlgCtrlID(hokBtn);
SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
IntPtr res = SendMessage(hokBtn, (int)0x00F5, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
if (res.ToInt32() == 1)
    MessageBox.Show("success");
```

That was actually a false positive if I'm not wrong; the default behaviour seemingly as a failsafe appears to be to close the dialog box. Rather, it was a positive that the cancel button can be clicked, but attempting to click Open or Save will generate the same yet in that context unwanted response...

It seems that this is a dialog box we're just going to have to deal with unless someone else could gratefully confirm otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

None of the code suggested worked, I ended up to use AutoIt script to close a Print Dialog, the code follows:

```
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]", "Print", 20)
WinActivate($hWnd)
WinWaitActive("[CLASS:#32770]", "Print", 10)
Sleep(100)
Send("{ENTER}")
```